Prioritize Kestrel for responsiveness over backend logic
When a .NET Core app is using Kestrel Server for serving a basic web application and in the same executable is logic (in different threads) which can exhaust the CPU in the background (which is not an error per se), is there a way to assign a higher priority to anything Kestrel related?
One way I could think of, was to use a separate executable for the logic and host 2 processes with different priorities, but maybe there is a way to have it in one file?
The problem is, when the CPU is going towards 100% utilization, the server needs much more time to answer a request.
For the sake of completeness:
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static Action runAction => new Action(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < int.MaxValue; x++)
                {
                }
            }
        });

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            var app = builder.Build();

            app.MapGet("/", () => { Task.Run(runAction); return "Hello World!"; });

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

Take care
The more often you access the page, the more the cpu will be used...

Let me begin with saying that your approach is highly questionable in its nature, spawning fire-and-forget, heavy CPU tasks like that.
That said, I would recommend switching from Task.Run to the good old Thread.Start, where you can easily specify a thread's priproty:
Thread t = new Thread(() => {/* your code */ });
t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
t.Start();


Yea, I agree :) The high cpu load tasks are spawned by another library, it is just an simplified down version of what is happening, roughly. I will check if there is a way to change the way the tasks are created, I know that there is a ThreadPool in use. Thx

@mayen a way for them not to start with each request is perhaps creating your own managing service, which would prevent further spawnage of uncontrollable threads. Or perhaps that library supports cancellation. Or by some other means.
